# I want to show all the images name in the browser . how will that be possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Database Screenshot**

[image: screenshot]

**Query:**

```
$id   =  isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '';
$qry  =  "SELECT `image` FROM product_images WHERE product_id = '".$id."';";
$res  =  mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
$row  =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
```

**Question:**

I want to show all the images name in the browser . how will that be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '';
$qry = 'SELECT image FROM product_images WHERE product_id = \'' . $conn->real_escape_string($id) . '\'';
$res = mysqli_query($qry, $conn);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    echo $row . '<br />' . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// absolute or relative path
$base_path = 'http://domain.com/uploads/'; 

$id   =  isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '';
$qry  =  "SELECT image FROM product_images WHERE product_id = '".$id."'";
$res  =  mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)
{
while ($row  =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $image_name = $row['image'];
    $image_path = $base_path.$image_name;

    // To display image name
    echo 'Image name = '.$image_name.'<br />';

    //To display image
    echo '<img src="'.$image_path.'" width="" height="" alt="" title="" />';
}
}
?>
```